# Hints on migrating GWT to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, gwt

With the end of the development plugin, the fun has gone out of GWT development. Every small change triggers endless recompilation and then I'm still debugging half Java half Javascript in the browser.

I'm thinking about migrating to AngularJS. Any hints on how to approach this?

Should I first switch my RPC Servlets to webservices returning JSON?

I'm also using GXT grids. How to best replace these?

Comment: I would suggest wait before migrating. Singular is releasing soon. Singular = GWT+Angular. Checkout the Google I/O video. And you will find out. That's the way to go. It will just require you to redo the UI keeping others intact

Comment: I agree, I'd hang around a bit and see what happens ☺

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Super Dev mode? This makes development a lot better as you use the browser dev tools to debug and it makes use of source maps. In my opinion, it has made GWT relevant again.

Do your backend first by converting your RPC servlets to an equivalent REST interface.  Then you can use any front-end MVC framework - Angular, native mobile, or whatever.

For GXT grids, AngularUI has a grid component. http://ui-grid.info/. You could also use ExtJS grids.